# how to make database robust to process kills with sqlite postgress and sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am using python and sqlalchemy to manage a sqlite database (in the future I plan to replace sqlite with postgres).

The operations I do are `INSERT`, `SELECT` and `DELETE` and all these operations are part of a python script that runs every hour.

Each one of these operation can take a considerable amount of time due to the large amount of data.

Now in certain circumstances the python script may be killed by an external process.  How can I make sure that my database is not corrupted if the script is killed while reading / writing  from the DB?

Comment: Relevant docs: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html

Comment: From the link above killing a process while writing is not a cause of data corruption.  Am I wrong?

Comment: It should not be: https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 4):

Well, you use a database.

Databases implement ACID properties (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science))).  To the extent possible, these guarantee the integrity of the data, even when transactions are not complete.

The issue that you are focusing on is dropped connections.  I think dropped connections usually result in a transaction being rolled back (I'm not sure if there are exceptions).  That is, the database ignores everything since the last commit.

So, the database protects you against *internal* corruption.  Your data model might become invalid, if the sequence of operations is stopped at an arbitrary place.  The solution to this is to wrap such operations into a transaction, so the transaction is rolled back.

There is a (small) danger of databases getting corrupted when the hardware or software they are running on suddenly "disappears".  This is rare and there are safeguards.  And, this is not the problem that you are concerned with (unless your SQLite instance is part of your python process).

Comment: To amplify: absent extraordinary effort, you're using SQLite as a library, and its code is running in the same process as your application.  SQLite takes great care never to leave the on-disk information in an unrecoverable state.  At any time, if the lights go out, the database is in a known state and is useable.  On restart, uncommitted transactions are rolled back.  Anything less is considered a bug.  Your task is to ensure you're using transactions to represent logical units of work in your database design.

Comment: something that I do not understand is if I should explicitly use transactions to make the code more robust. In case when?

Comment: @Donbeo . . . I can't answer that.  It depends on what you are implementing with your logic.